# Word for when a life event (like a vacation) is coming to an end and you feel an immense feeling of sadness due to not wanting to leave

Tags: single-word-requests

I get this feeling every time after I leave somewhere where I’ve gotten comfortable being in.

Comment: *pang*, as in *pang of sorrow*, *pang of sadness*, etc.

Comment: Do you want a term before or after you leave? The question sounds like before, the body sounds like after. The top voted answer is based on after, though this seems easier to find a word for.

Comment: Bet the Germans have a word that means exactly this...

Answer (score 12):

I suspect the closest one can get with a single word is **wistfulness**.

> *wistfulness* [noun] [noncount]:
>
> a feeling of sadness because you are thinking about something that is
> impossible or in the past

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wistfulness)]

> If there's a vague sense of yearning behind an action, you can say
> it's done wistfully. People sigh wistfully, gaze wistfully, and wave
> goodbye wistfully – thinking about the past or what you are leaving
> behind with a little bit of sadness.

[[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wistfully)]

'Nostalgia' is rooted further in the past.

Answer (score 5):

Specific to holidays, as per your title, you have:

> [Post vacation syndrome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-vacation_blues) (PVS) is commonly called the blues. PVS typically appears in individuals who have recently returned to work following a holiday of a week or more. Typical symptoms include a lack of focus and difficulty concentrating.

Answer (score 4):

The feeling can be described as **[bittersweet](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bittersweet)**, defined as per the Cambridge Dictionary:

> containing a mixture of sadness and happiness

For [example](https://www.cocoandvera.com/2019/12/04/bittersweet/):

> The end of a vacation is always bittersweet. After days of fun and
> festivity, it’s hard not to be happy, even if you know all the joyful
> adventuring is about to come to an end.

It can equally be applied to other largely positive major life events such as graduation or a promotion that takes you to a new city.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. OP seems to be looking for a word that captures the sadness about something good ending (a purely negative emotion), not "a mixture of sadness and happiness".

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word or an established term but **anticipatory sadness** is used for this feeling. (Note that it differs from *anticipatory grief* which is more intense).

As you mentioned, you feel sad *before* the good thing ends because you know it is ending, hence the modifier *anticipatory*. I doubt there is a specific single word, which there isn't even any in the dictionary of obscure sorrows. Japanese *mono no aware* comes close but it has its own intricacies tied in with Japanese culture.

Comment: Ok I noticed that you feel sad before the good thing ends per the question title; but then, you say "after" in the question body. I can delete or modify my answer based on your clarification. Perhaps you can provide more details in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say this, but the best I can come up with is "That feeling you get when a great vacation is about to end."

Comment: If every feeling could be reduced to a single word, would we have Proust?

Answer (score 0):

- **longing**
- **yearning**

These words express a wanting for something. But there is a nuance here implying that the thing being wanted is something the speaker has previously experienced or come in contact with, and therefore feels a connection with.

You could express a longing, or yearning for a place you have been to before, or a time in your life that has passed.

Contrarily, (to my knowledge) it would be strange to say you you've been *longing* to try scuba diving. This is because *“try”* implies you haven't done it yet, and so a connection to the experience would not yet be established.

**Note:** What I mean by “to my knowledge” is that I'm basing this description on how I've seen/heard these words used. But dictionary definitions I've checked do not mention a preexisting connection to the thing longed for. Nonetheless, I'm going to give this answer based on my gut feeling. (I welcome discussion on this in comments.)